# Ubuntu 22.04 OVA Cloud Image does not get a DHCP IPv4 address in vSphere

Tags: vmware, 22.04, vmware-tools

I imported both Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 OVA into vSphere like this:

```
govc import.ova -name ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-md -folder vm/DIA_RnD/RMD/buildenvironment/templates https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/releases/20.04/release/ubuntu-20.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova
govc import.ova -name ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-md -folder vm/DIA_RnD/RMD/buildenvironment/templates https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/releases/22.04/release/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova
```

For Ubuntu 20.04 the VM created from the template works and gets an IP:
[20.04 vSphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPo9i.png)

For Ubuntu 22.04 the VM does not get an IP:
[22.04 vSphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4V67S.png)

I have also tried to use import.spec and pass the options json file but same result, it works for 20.04 but not for 22.04.

```
govc import.spec ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova | jq . > 2204.json
govc import.ova -name ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64-md -options 2204.json -folder vm/DIA_RnD/RMD/buildenvironment/templates https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/releases/22.04/release/ubuntu-22.04-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you import the cloud-image template and before converting it to a template, you may have to enable the OVF environment.

Go to *Configure* → *Settings* → *vApp Options* and enable  *OVF environment* for the IP allocation scheme, as well as *VMware Tools* under *OVF Details*.

After that, convert the modified VM to a template and deploy new VMs using that template.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Now I have to figure out how to automate this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in vCenter, unfortunately :(